# css - Spacing the list items dynamically

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I want to display the list items horizontally, but the spacing between the items must be dynamic. i.e depending on the longest item all others must be aligned. So specifying a `fixed width` for an item won't work.

Say when we have

```
Element 1     Element 2     Very long element can also be here      This is one more element which is longer
Longer than Element1   Next element   More ones
```

I want it to be displayed like

```
Element 1             Element 2        Very long element can also be here    This is one more element which is longer
Longer than Element1  Next element     More ones
```

`Element 2` must be moved right because we have a longer item at the next row.

https://jsfiddle.net/yo4yqtpL/

How can I achieve this?

Thanks..

Comment: you can use html tables

Comment: @thewbmstr The  idea is not to specify width for an item. i.e number of columns beforehand

Comment: There is no CSS method of achieving this result. Javascript would be required.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```css
table {
    width: 100%;
}

table td {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Element 1</td>
            <td>Element 2</td>
            <td>Very long element can also be here</td>
            <td>This is one more element which is longer</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Longer than Element1</td>
            <td>Next element</td>
            <td>More ones</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this wraps an item to next line.And I don't know how many elements must be placed on one row. That'll depend on the length of the items.

Comment: I mean, the loading of the data (list items) will be in loop. So I will not know when to start a new row

Comment: javascript ajax. (angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

try this code and see if it helps

```
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
li {
  min-width: 5em;
  list-style: none;
}

<ul>
<li>Element 1</li>
<li>Element 2</li>
<li>Very long element can also be here</li>
<li>This is one more element which is longer</li>
<li> Longer than Element1</li>
</ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yo4yqtpL/8/

Comment: Still `Element2` is not aligned based on the item in the second row.

Comment: check the updated fiddle in the answer and increase or decrease the margin in div class as per your design requirement..

Comment: The data that I'll load will be dynamic. Your answer groups the contents into div (assuming the data as static)

Comment: there was no way i could have known that the data loaded will be dynamic but in this case use jquery to add items to div and you may use classname for the divs to add specific items in a particular div..this structure will hold..